# Adding a dot where a canvas is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to make an image editable on in the browser. I found [this](https://www.codicode.com/art/how_to_draw_on_a_html5_canvas_with_a_mouse.aspx), and I tried to re-purpose this code for my use. This is what I ended up with:

```
export default class CanvasComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.lastX = 0;
        this.lastY = 0;
        this.ctx = 0;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, nextProps.width, nextProps.height);
        };
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(nextProps.image)
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        canvas.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            this.Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
        })
    };

    Draw = (x, y) => {
        console.log('drawing');
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        this.ctx.lineJoin = "round";
        this.ctx.moveTo(this.lastX, this.lastY);
        this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.stroke();
        this.lastX = x;
        this.lastY = y;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <canvas onClick={this.handleClick} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} id={'canvas'}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I really don't know canvas (first time using it) so I am probably doing something really stupid (plz don't yell).

Right now the code acts like this: https://youtu.be/4rvGigRvJ8E

I was unable to make it into a gif. Sorry

What I want to be happening:
When the user clicks on the image, in the place of clicking I want a dot to appear. How can I achieve this?

New `Draw` method

```
Draw = (x, y) => {
    console.log('drawing');
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    // x, y are the cords, 5 is the radius of the circle and the last 2 things specify full circle.
    this.ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.lastX = x;
    this.lastY = y;
};
```

Comment: The video seems to be un-available, could you potentially describe the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I set it to private. It's public now

Comment: You can remove the `lineTo` and `moveTo` commands and replace it with `this.ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI)`. You can remove the lastX and lastY variables

Comment: This almost works. But the dot disappears/doesn't stay on the canvas. It appears for a second after clicking, and disappears. What can cause it? I'll add my updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draw code seems to be trying to draw a line instead of a circle…

To draw a circle take a look at this example.

```js
this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
this.ctx.lineWidth = 5;
// x, y are the cords, 5 is the radius of the circle and the last 2 things specify full circle.
this.ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
this.ctx.stroke();
```

Documented https://developer.mozilla.org/kab/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs

Also you seem to be trying to attach a lister instead of acting on the listening, the function you pass to onClick will be called every click, no need to attach a click listener in that as well.

Comment: This almost works. But the dot disappears/doesn't stay on the canvas. It appears for a second after clicking, and disappears. What can cause it? I'll add my updated code

Comment: For future reference: The disappearing of dots was caused by React rerendering the image. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744356/7055769 for more info