# React parent passing props to a child causes infinite loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, recursion

What I'm trying to achieve:

I want the user to be able to place red dots on a picture rendered in a canvas. That's it.

What's happening?

Every time I add said dots (`CanvasComponent`), it is there, and then disappears a second later. I figured that's because the canvas is re-rendering over and over. I added a `console.log` to `componentWillReceiveProps` and it consoled up to a couple of k in a minute, and crashed my browser.

I cannot see where the loop is coming from, maybe someone here has more skills or luck.

Here's my code:

`DisplayPictureComponent`

```
setDimensions = (width, height) => {
    console.log('dimensions')
    this.setState({width: width, height: height})
};

render() {
    const {width, height} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <CanvasComponent width={width} height={height} image={this.props.image}/>
            <ImageComponent
                setDimensions={this.setDimensions}
                image={this.props.image}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`ImageComponent`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('imageProps')
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async e => {
        await this.setState({image: e.target.result});
        const image = document.getElementById('image');
        const {naturalHeight, naturalWidth} = image;

        nextProps.setDimensions(naturalWidth, naturalHeight);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(nextProps.image);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <img style={{display: 'none'}} id={'image'} src={this.state.image} alt={''}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

CanvasComponent

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('canvasProps');
    // console.log('props');
    this.ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        this.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, nextProps.width, nextProps.height);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(nextProps.image)
}

handleClick = (e) => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.Draw(e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop);
};

Draw = (x, y) => {
    console.log('drawing');
};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <canvas onClick={this.handleClick} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} id={'canvas'}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: what triggers the `setDimensions` on the `ImageComponent`

Comment: Loading of the picture `reader.onload = async e => {...`

Comment: in Image component nextProps.setDimension (), what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to get the dimensions of the image uploaded by the user, to create a canvas with the right width and height

Comment: i haven't tried the code yet, but i think the call to the `componentWillReceiveProps` changes the props, thereby calling itself.
 a hack around this would be to compare if the current width and height isn't the same as the next.

Comment: @Obed yup that solved it. Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the call to the `componentWillReceiveProps` changes the props, thereby calling itself. 
A hack around this would be to compare if the current width and height isn't the same as the next.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 console.log('imageProps')
 const reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = async e => {
    await this.setState({image: e.target.result});
    const image = document.getElementById('image');
    const {naturalHeight, naturalWidth} = image;
    if ((nextProps.width !== this.props.width) ||(nextProps.height !== this.props.height) ) {
    nextProps.setDimensions(naturalWidth, naturalHeight);
    }
};
    reader.readAsDataURL(nextProps.image);
}
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated you can use the alternative

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  // Called after a component is instantiated or before it receives new props.
  // Return an object to update state in response to prop changes.
  // Return null to indicate no change to state.
}
```

You can refer to this [RFC](https://github.com/bvaughn/rfcs/blob/7042a2abcbdc90b4a7784ea6a753ce9abac169d9/text/0000-static-lifecycle-methods.md) to understand more about why this change was made.

Comment: your current code might need some refactoring to work with `getDerivedStateFromProps`